# MySQL how to add an extra column to a search query that has unioned two rows from different tables to show from which table it comes from

Tags: mysql

So I have unioned two rows from 2 different tables, which works quite alright.

```
SELECT CONCAT(contactFirstName," ",contactLastName), customerNumber FROM classicmodels.customers 
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName), employeeNumber FROM classicmodels.employees;
```

What I am struggling to do is to have another column that shows from which table I got each name, since I have to sort them alphabetically later, which means I can´t just seperate them by table 1 and table 2 through a limit or something.

Comment: in your select, before the concat, have `tablename = 'tableA'` in one and then `tablename = 'tableB'` in the other

Comment: Given that the column names for a unioned query are taken from the first query only and ignored in all other queries, how would this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your own column and use it as the first value to order by, eg

```
SELECT CONCAT(contactFirstName," ",contactLastName) as FullName, customerNumber, 1 as Source
FROM classicmodels.customers 
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName), employeeNumber, 2 
FROM classicmodels.employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add table name in the form of String with a specific alias.

```
SELECT CONCAT(contactFirstName," ",contactLastName), customerNumber, 'customers' as data_source FROM classicmodels.customers 
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName), employeeNumber, 'employees' as data_source FROM classicmodels.employees;
```